# Python list definition - inserting elements or not depending on a condition

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I can define a list such that:

```
c = some_condition # True or False
l = [
    1, 2,   # always
    3 if c else 4
]
# l = [ 1, 2, 3 ] if c is True, [ 1, 2, 4 ] otherwise
```

But **how can I define a list that is `[1,2,3]` if c is true, `[1,2]` otherwise?**

```
l = [
    1, 2,
    3 if c    # syntax error
]

l = [
    1, 2,
    3 if c else None    # makes [1,2,None]
]

l = [
    1, 2,
    3 if c else []    # makes [1,2,[]]
]

# This is the best that I could do
l = (
    [
        1, 2,
    ]
    +
    ([3] if c1 else [])  # parentheses are mandatory
    )

# Of course, I know I could
l = [1, 2]
if c:
    l.append(3)
```

In addition, I want to know how to insert multiple elements when a condition is true: `3, 4` instead of `3` for example.

In Perl, for example, I could do:

```
@l = (
    1, 2,
    $c1 ? 3 : (),        # empty list that shall be flattened in outer list
    $c2 ? (4,5) : (6,7), # multiple elements
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c = some_condition # True or False

l = [1, 2] + [x for x in [3] if c]
print(l)
```

output >>>

```
[1, 2, 3] # when c = True
[1, 2]    # when c = False
```

you can extend it as you wish

```
l = [1, 2] + [x for x in [3] if c] + [x for x in [4] if not c]
```

output >>>

```
[1, 2, 3] # when c = True
[1, 2, 4]    # when c = False
```

Comment: Oh, now I can get rid of "else []" and parentheses. This looks better. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can come to that is using a separately defined generator function:

```
def maker(condition):
    yield 1
    yield 2
    if condition:
        yield 3
        yield 4

print(list(maker(True)))
print(list(maker(False)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2]
```

That said, Python isn't really meant for such operations, and they will therefore be clunky. It is in general more idiomatic to filter a list based on a predicate, or else create an identically shaped boolean `numpy` array and use masking.

Answer (score 0):

`[x for x in range(1,5) if x<3 or c]`

Comment: Thank you, but 1,2,.. are just sample values for this post. In my real code, they are different and not sequential numbers.